# How to hide left button after page load in Twitter bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to hide left button after page load in Twitter bootstrap carousel?

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

My try(it works after first action, I need all time):

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', '', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.children('.carousel-control').show();
    if($('.carousel-inner .item:first').hasClass('active')) {
      $this.children('.left.carousel-control').hide();
    } 
    else if($('.carousel-inner .item:last').hasClass('active')) {
      $this.children('.right.carousel-control').hide();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply hide the left button after page load. Since it will always start at the first slide.

```
$('#myCarousel > .left.carousel-control').hide();
```

Or, manually trigger a `slid` event after page load.

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', '', function () {
  ...
}).trigger('slid');
```